# How I can exclude NA from a density ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to create a density plot with Yes/No data of antiepileptic therapy by length of hospital stay..
I'm trying to remove NA from my ggplot2 density plot, but it doesn't work nd i don't understand why...

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Here are my variables:

```
db$deg
  [1] NA  7 NA  0  0 NA  0 NA  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  6 25 NA
 [19] NA  0  0 NA NA  0 NA  1  3 NA  0  5 NA  3 NA 15  0 NA
 [37]  0  0 NA  0  0  0 NA  0  0 12 NA 10  0  0 NA  0  0  0
 [55] 15  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA  3  0  8 NA  0  2  4  9 NA
 [73]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 23  0  0  0  0  0  9  5 NA  0
 [91]  5  0  0  0  5 NA NA  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0 NA  0  0
[109]  0  0 NA 19  0  0  0  0 NA NA NA NA 11  0  0  3  0  7
[127] NA  0  0 NA NA  0  0  0  0  0 NA NA  2  2  0 NA  0  0
[145]  0  0 NA NA  9  5 NA  0  2 28 15  0  0 NA  0 20 NA 16
[163]  0 NA  3 NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA  0  0  0  1 NA  0  4 NA
[181] NA  0 NA NA  0  0  0  3  0  5  1  0  7  3  0  4  0  0
[199]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0 14
[217]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  1  0  6  0 21  1  0  0
[235]  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  5  0  0  0  0  0 15 17  1  0  5
[253]  0  0  0 15  0  0  9  0  0  0  0  9  0  0  5  0  0  0

db$Antiepileptic
  [1] <NA> No   <NA> No   No   <NA> No   <NA> No   No  
 [11] <NA> <NA> No   No   No   No   No   <NA> <NA> No  
 [21] No   <NA> <NA> No   <NA> No   No   <NA> No   No  
 [31] <NA> No   <NA> No   No   <NA> No   No   <NA> No  
 [41] No   No   <NA> <NA> No   No   <NA> No   No   No  
 [51] <NA> No   No   <NA> No   No   No   <NA> No   <NA>
 [61] No   <NA> <NA> No   No   No   <NA> No   No   No  
 [71] No   <NA> No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No  
 [81] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   <NA> No  
 [91] No   No   No   No   No   <NA> <NA> No   No   No  
[101] No   No   No   <NA> No   <NA> No   No   No   No  
[111] <NA> No   No   No   No   No   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
[121] No   No   No   No   No   No   <NA> No   Yes  <NA>
[131] <NA> No   No   No   No   Yes  <NA> <NA> No   No  
[141] No   <NA> No   No   No   No   <NA> <NA> No   No  
[151] <NA> No   No   No   No   No   No   <NA> No   No  
[161] <NA> No   No   <NA> No   <NA> No   No   No   No  
[171] <NA> <NA> No   No   No   No   <NA> No   No   <NA>
[181] <NA> No   <NA> <NA> No   No   No   No   No   No  
[191] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No  
[201] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No  
[211] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No  
[221] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   Yes 
[231] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No  
[241] No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No   No  
[251] No   No   No   Yes  Yes  No   No   No   No   No  
[261] No   No   No   No   Yes  No   No   No   No   No
```

Here's my code:

```
p8 <- ggplot(db, aes(x = deg, fill = Antiepileptic, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_density(position="identity", alpha=0.6, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Hospitalization",
                     breaks = seq(0, 31, 5),
                     limits=c(0, 31)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Density") +
  ggtitle("Hospitalization by Antiepileptic therapy") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
        text = element_text(size = 12, family = "Tahoma")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Accent")
p8
```

here's my plot:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop `NA` before you go into `ggplot`.  You can either drop only `Antiepileptic` cases with

```
db %>%
  filter(!is.na(Antiepileptic)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = deg, fill = Antiepileptic, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
  ...
```

Or drop all rows with `NA` using `complete.cases()`:

```
db %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  ggplot(db, aes(x = deg, fill = Antiepileptic, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  ...
```

Here's your code with `NA` dropped from `Antiepileptic`.  Data as `dput` provided at the end.

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Antiepileptic)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = deg, fill = Antiepileptic, na.rm = TRUE)) +
  geom_density(position="identity", alpha=0.6, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Hospitalization",
                     breaks = seq(0, 31, 5),
                     limits=c(0, 31)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Density") +
  ggtitle("Hospitalization by Antiepileptic therapy") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14, family = "Tahoma", face = "bold"),
        text = element_text(size = 12, family = "Tahoma")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Accent")
```

[image]

Data:

```
structure(list(deg = c(NA, 7, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 25, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 3, NA, 0, 
5, NA, 3, NA, 15, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 12, NA, 
10, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 3, 0, 8, 
NA, 0, 2, 4, 9, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
9, 5, NA, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 11, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 7, NA, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 2, 2, 0, NA, 
0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 9, 5, NA, 0, 2, 28, 15, 0, 0, NA, 0, 20, 
NA, 16, 0, NA, 3, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 
4, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 1, 0, 7, 3, 0, 4, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 6, 0, 21, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 17, 1, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 
0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0), Antiepileptic = c(NA, 
"No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", NA, 
"No", "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", 
"No", NA, "No", "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", 
"No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", NA, "No", 
NA, NA, "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
NA, NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", NA, "No", 
"No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "Yes", NA, 
NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", NA, NA, "No", "No", "No", 
NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", "No", NA, "No", 
NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", NA, 
"No", "No", NA, NA, "No", NA, NA, "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -270L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```